# Crontab reboot job reboot multiple times instead of once

Tags: cron, reboot

I am trying to schedule my debian jessie machine to shutdown at 9:00 p.m. every 3 days. I currently use a cronjob:

```
00 21 */3 * * root bash /home/pi/scripts/reboot.sh
```

where reboot.sh is:

```
sudo reboot
```

The machine shuts down on schedule but what is strange is that it just keeps rebooting for several times. how am I able to get rid of this issue. is this related to maybe the RTC clock no have enough time to update itself and so the cron job still thinks the time is still 9... I really doubt this.. any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its better to use the internal command shutdown instead of using the script. `shutdown now` shuts the computer and `-r` flag is for reboot system. you can also pass specific time instead of now like `shutdown -r 11:00`.

For now you can use

```
shutdown -r now
```

Comment: changing "sudo reboot" to "shutdown -r now" did not fix the problem. i have just tested this now and my system keeps rebooting